# JS classlist doesn’t work fully in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have three divs, each contains another div which are hidden by a class called **none**. when I click the button  *show squares*, the
function  **displaySquares** should remove all **none** classes, but it doesn't. ***lOb.classList*** is returning **undefined** at a certain iteration and I don't know why? Any help will be appreciated.

```js
        function displaySquares(x){        
            var dr = document.getElementsByClassName(x),pl=dr.length,i=0;

            for (i; i < pl; i++) {
                var lOb = dr[i]; 

                if (lOb.classList) { 
                    if (lOb.classList.contains(x)) {
                        lOb.classList.remove(x);
                    }
                } else { //fallback for classList
                    var r = new RegExp("\\b" + x+ "\\b", "g");
                    if (r.test(lOb.className)) {
                        lOb.className = lOb.className.replace(r, "");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
    .clcn{
        width:130px;
        height:130px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    .clcn2{
        position:absolute;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        background: yellow;  
        border:1px solid blue;
        }
    .none{
        display:none;
        }
```

```html
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<button  onclick="displaySquares('none');">show squares</button>
```

Comment: Using `.querySelectorAll` will return a static list that will not suffer the problems of the live HTMLcollection described below. `function displaySquares(x){ let dr = document.querySelectorAll('.' + x); dr.forEach(element => element.classList.remove(x));}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you are changing the name of the elements in each iteration so

- the first iteration you have 3 elements with a class none and I = 0 so you have an element then you remove 1 so now you have 2
- the second iteration you have 2 elements with a class none  and I = 1 so you have an element then you remove 1 so now you have 1
- the third iteration you have only 1 element with a class none in the "dr" array and I = 2 so you have no element in index 2 you have only one element in index 1 so dr[2] is undefined
- the solution I made is that I always get the first element index 0 and change it
- reason why this happened is that dr is a reference to dom so when you change the dom you change dr cause it's just a pointer to the ref
  hope I have helped

```js
function displaySquares(x){        
            var dr = document.getElementsByClassName(x),pl=dr.length,i=0;

            for (i; i < pl; i++) {
// fix 
                var lOb = dr[0]; 

                if (lOb.classList) { 
                    if (lOb.classList.contains(x)) {
                        lOb.classList.remove(x);
                    }
                } else { //fallback for classList
                    var r = new RegExp("\\b" + x+ "\\b", "g");
                    if (r.test(lOb.className)) {
                        lOb.className = lOb.className.replace(r, "");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
.clcn{
        width:130px;
        height:130px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    .clcn2{
        position:absolute;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        background: yellow;  
        border:1px solid blue;
        }
    .none{
        display:none;
        }
```

```html
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<div  class="clcn">
    <div  class="clcn2 none"></div>
</div>
<button  onclick="displaySquares('none');">show squares</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, every time you remove the classname "none" from one of the elements during the loop, the number of elements in the html collection (the "dr" variable) changes. So it starts at 3, then in the next iteration it's 2 etc. And because you're incrementing "i", you're basically skipping an element.

One possible solution would be to use a while loop instead of a for loop so you just keep looping until there are no elements left.

```
                while (dr.length) {
                var lOb = dr[0]; 
                                            
                if (lOb.classList) { 
                    if (lOb.classList.contains(x)) {
                        lOb.classList.remove(x);
                    }
                } else { //fallback for classList
                    var r = new RegExp("\\b" + x+ "\\b", "g");
                    if (r.test(lOb.className)) {
                        lOb.className = lOb.className.replace(r, "");
                                                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mozilla warns [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) about returned value from `getElementsByClassName`.

> This is a live HTMLCollection. Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.

Trying to remove a class like that will not work for the rest of iteration because it works like a "queue".

```js
function selfRemove(class_name){
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(class_name);
  while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].classList.remove(class_name);
  }
}
```